# Updating my csv file with data from XML in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

For educational purposes I'm trying to update my CSV file via an XML sheet.
Update my CSV where client equals nummer (without hardcoding it) doensn't work. Anyone who can see what I'm doing wrong?

XML:

```
    <wijzigen>
    <klant nummer="4">
        <stad>Troy</stad>
        <provincie>TR</provincie>
        <provincieVoluit>Troas</provincieVoluit>
        <adres>happy horse street 27</adres>
        <postcode>1200BC</postcode>
    </klant>
    <klant nummer="7">
        <stad>Achaea</stad>
    </klant>
</wijzigen>
```

Powershell:

```
function Wijzig-Klant{
$klantnummer = $wijziging.nummer
$stad = $wijziging.stad
$provincie = $wijziging.provincie
$provincieVoluit = $wijziging.provincieVoluit
$adres = $wijziging.adres
$postcode = $wijziging.postcode

$data = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Projecten\PowerShell\Data_v1.0.csv" -Delimiter ";"

$update = $data | Where-Object {$_.klantnummer -eq $klantnummer} | ForEach-Object {
           $_.stad = $stad 
           $_.provincie = $provincie
           $_.provincieVoluit = $provincieVoluit
           $_.adres = $adres
           $_.postcode = $postcode
}
$update | Export-Csv ("C:\Projecten\PowerShell\" + $datumVandaag + "Data_v1.0.csv") -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

}

Read the XML File in powershell for the data:

```
$wijziging = $XMLDocument.klantadministratie.wijzigen.klant
[xml]$XMLDocument = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Projecten\PowerShell\XML Wijzigingen v1.0.xml'
```

Comment: Where are your variables coming from?

Comment: My bad:
$wijziging = $XMLDocument.klantadministratie.wijzigen.klant

Thats the import from my XML to read the data

Comment: How are you importing the XML?  Your XML example and your code don't match up.

Comment: Updated above, forgot 1 line

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your XML schema is actually:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<klantadministratie>
    <wijzigen>
        <klant nummer="4">
            <stad>Troy</stad>
            <provincie>TR</provincie>
            <provincieVoluit>Troas</provincieVoluit>
            <adres>happy horse street 27</adres>
            <postcode>1200BC</postcode>
        </klant>
        <klant nummer="7">
            <stad>Achaea</stad>
        </klant>
    </wijzigen>
</klantadministratie>
'@
```

based on your example.  With this knowledge, you need `null` checks since not all values are populated:

```
$path = 'C:\Projecten\PowerShell\Data_v1.0.csv'
Import-Csv -Path $path -Delimiter ';' | ForEach-Object {
    $set = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//klant[@nummer='$($PSItem.klantnummer)']")

    if ($set.stad)            { $PSItem.stad = $set.stad }
    if ($set.provincie)       { $PSItem.provincie = $set.provincie }
    if ($set.provincieVoluit) { $PSItem.provincieVoluit = $set.provincieVoluit }
    if ($set.adres)           { $PSItem.adres = $set.adres }
    if ($set.postcode)        { $PSItem.postcode = $set.postcode }

    $PSItem # return the updated row to the pipeline
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Projecten\PowerShell\${datumVandaag}Data_v1.0.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

Lastly, I think your problem was not returning the object back to the pipeline.